# Primefaces facet header button

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable in Primefaces:

```
    <p:dataTable var="feedback" value="#{actionDetailsView.action.feedback}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Feedback
                </f:facet>

                <p:column headerText="Date">
                    ...
                </p:column>
```

Now I want to have a button (Add Feedback) inside the header on the right hand side. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Why not **try** to put a button in the header and ask afterwards if it e.g. does not work or whatever... (now it kind of looks like you are 'lazy' which I assume you are not. And the 'official' answer to your question _"Is this somehow possible?"_ would be a **yes**, nothing more. And accepting a good answer is common practice in stackoverflow. Please do

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is. You may define the button as a child of the `f:facet` tag.

```
<p:dataTable>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:commandButton /> <!-- either here -->
    </f:facet>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:commandButton /> <!-- or here -->
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

Comment: With this, the button is right next to the text. Is it somehow possible to align it to the right hand side?

Comment: via CSS, that's not related to JSF